# Assigning an attribute of a directive to a scope value

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a directive as such :

```
<div custom-directive option1="Sam" option2="Pam" modelname="position.name">
```

I want to assign option1 and option2(it will depend on which i click) as the value of the scope i create on the global scope with modelname as the name of the scope .

and directive definition is as such

```
user.directive('customDirective',['$parse',function($parse){
      return{
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: 'false', //because i want to expose the scope globally
          link: function(scope,iElement,iAttrs){
          // create a scope with modelname as its name;
             using $parse maybe.. but i dont know how ..
          // create the template for the directive
          var optionElement1 = angular.element( "<span>"+iAttrs['option1']+"</span>");
          var seperator = angular.element("<span>"+" / "+"</span>");
          var optionElement2 = angular.element("<span>"+iAttrs['option2']+"</span>");
                iElement.append(optionElement1).append(seperator).append(optionElement2);
          optionElement1.click(function(){
          // assign iAttrs['option1'] to the scope created
          })
          optionElement2.click(function(){
          // assign iAttrs['option2'] to the scope created

          })
          }
         }

 }])
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Posting it just in case someone faces the same issue ..

I used ngModelController to do that, used ng-model only instead of modelname attribute

```
<div custom-directive option1="Sam" option2="Pam" ng-model="position.name">
```

in the directive  definition :

```
user.directive('customDirective',[function(){
  return{
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope,iElement,iAttrs,ctrl){
      var optionElement1 = angular.element( "<span>"+iAttrs['option1']+"</span>");
      var seperator = angular.element("<span>"+" / "+"</span>");
      var optionElement2 = angular.element("<span>"+iAttrs['option2']+"</span>");
      iElement.append(optionElement1).append(seperator).append(optionElement2);
      optionElement1.click(function(){
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(iAttrs['option1']);
        });
      })
      optionElement2.click(function(){
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(iAttrs['option2']);
        });
      })
     }
  }

}])
```